# Laravel 5.3 - redirect after login

Tags: redirect, laravel-5.3

I am trying to redirect user to `/admin/magazines` after login instead of to `/`. I have tried with changing the `$redirect` variable in `Auth\LoginController`, tried with also changing the function handle in `Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`, and also with putting the function into `LoginController` like this:

```
public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/magazines');
        }
    }
```

But nothing worked, every time after a login I have been redirected to `/`

This is my routes file:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);

Auth::routes();

//Backend admin routes...
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::resource('magazines', 'MagazinesController');
});
```

Comment: Just change `$redirectTo` on `LoginController` that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in **Auth/LoginController** there is protected **`$redirectTo = '/home';`**
just change **'/home'** to **'/admin/magazine'**. and with this every time a user login it will redirect him to this URL.